# Row by Row, delete entire row if Cell H= Cell I

Tags: excel, vba

If Cell H1 = Cell I1, delete entire row. Then next row, Cell H2 <> Cell I2, keep. Then next row.

I would like to delete entire row if both cell of the row are the same. I searched and this the closest to what I want to achieve and amend the code.

```
Sub CellAequalCellB ()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = ws.Range("H1:I" & lastRow)

    ' filter and delete all but header row
    With rng
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=" .AutoFilter field:=2 "

SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    ' turn off the filters
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

However when I run, entirerow.delete have error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AutoFilter code has many mistakes so I've changed the method to a simple backwards loop.

```
sub CellAequalCellB ()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, i as long

    with ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        for i=lastrow to 1 step -1
            if .cells(i, "H") = .cells(i, "I") then _
                .rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        next i

    end with

End Sub
```

Comment: I'll work to improve it. Appreciated your help on this, do have a good day ahead!